# Cannot Convert UserQuery enum to enum

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to execute the code below (in LINQPad), and my LINQ statement is getting an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UserQuery.ResultCode>` to `UserQuery.ResultCode`.

Why?

Here is the code:

```
public enum ResultCode {
    Big,
    Bad,
    Messy
}

public class ValidationResult {
    public bool IsValid = false;
    public ResultCode Code;

    public override string ToString(){
        return String.Format("IsValid: {0}, Code: {1}",IsValid, Code);
    }
}

public class RuleMap {
    public Func<bool> Fact;
    public ResultCode Code;
    public List<int> Actions;
}


public class RulesProcessor{

    List<RuleMap> rules;

    public RulesProcessor(){
        rules = new List<RuleMap>{
            new RuleMap {Fact = CheckLeft, Code = ResultCode.Big,
                Actions = new List<int> {2, 3}
            },
            new RuleMap {Fact = CheckRight, Code = ResultCode.Bad,
                Actions = new List<int> {1, 2}
            },
            new RuleMap {Fact = CheckDown, Code = ResultCode.Messy,
                Actions = new List<int> {1, 3}
            },
        };
    }

    public bool CheckLeft(){
        return true;
    }

    public bool CheckRight(){
        return false;
    }

    public bool CheckDown(){
        return true;
    }

    public ValidationResult EvaluateRulesOnAction(int actionType){

        ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult();

        ResultCode badRule = from foo in rules
                                where !foo.Fact() && foo.Actions.Contains(actionType)
                                select foo.Code;


        if (badRule != null){
            result.Code = badRule;
        }else{
            result.IsValid = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

}

void Main()
{
    var foo = new RulesProcessor();

    foo.EvaluateRulesOnAction(1).Dump();
    foo.EvaluateRulesOnAction(3).Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that every LINQ query of the form `from x in y select x` returns an `IEnumerable<TypeOfX>`.

If you are sure that there can be a maximum of one bad rule, you can change your code to this:

```
ResultCode badRule = (from foo in rules 
                      where !foo.Fact() && foo.Actions.Contains(actionType) 
                      select foo.Code).SingleOrDefault();
```

If there can be more than one bad rule but you are only interested in the first one, use this:

```
ResultCode badRule = (from foo in rules 
                      where !foo.Fact() && foo.Actions.Contains(actionType) 
                      select foo.Code).FirstOrDefault();
```

The "OrDefault" in both queries indicates that you want to have the [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) of the returned type. For reference types this is `null`.

However, in your code, the query returns an enum of type `ResultCode`. Enums can't be `null`, so the `if` that comes after the query will never yield the expected results as `badRule == null` is always `false`.

You should change your code to this:

```
var badRule = (from foo in rules 
               where !foo.Fact() && foo.Actions.Contains(actionType) 
               select foo).FirstOrDefault(); 

if (badRule != null){
    result.Code = badRule.Code;
}else{
    result.IsValid = true;
}
```

Comment: In that case, I'd like to ...(from foo in rules...).FirstOrDefault... and have null returned if there was nothing.  How then?  Currently 'FirstOrDefault' returns a non-null value when no rule matched.

Comment: @BrentArias: Why do you think that? FirstOrDefault is specifically the version that returns `null` of nothing is matched. More precisely, it returns `default(ResultCode)` which is `null` for reference types. However, as you are returning an enum, that can't be `null`, so you code was bogus from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the query to.

```
        IEnumerable<ResultCode> badRule = from foo in rules
                            where !foo.Fact() && foo.Actions.Contains(actionType)
                            select foo.Code;
```

and changing ValidationResult to

```
    public IEnumerable<ResultCode> Code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error?

Your LINQ query returns a collection (IEnumerable) of ResultCodes, not a single ResultCode.

Answer (score 0):

Because this:

```
ResultCode badRule = from foo in rules
                     where !foo.Fact() && foo.Actions.Contains(actionType)
                     select foo.Code;
```

Returns a collection of ResultCodes and you are trying to assign it to a single ResultCode variable.

If you know there is only ever one result, then you could use First to select it and assign it to badRule. Or FirstOrDefault if there might be 1 or 0 results.